# Finding text inside link thats visible

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
page = urlopen("http://members.calbar.ca.gov/fal/Member/Detail//50225")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read()).find("div", {"id": "moduleMemberDetail"})

if soup.find("td",text=re.compile(r"e-mail:")) :
    email = soup.find("td",text=re.compile(r"email:")).findNext('td').encode_contents().strip()
print(email)
```

the output is

```
<span href="mailto:klwfge@rsrftff.edu" id="e0">dunpsr@tnkroqew<span>.</span>net</span>...
```

then I inspect the HTML with firebugs

it turns out has more than 1 span that its invisible. 
My question is to find text inside email link that visible??

Answer (score 1):

You should use `find_all` instead of `find`.

Answer (score 1):

if you wanted the href value maybe that would help:

```
for node in soup.find_all('span', attrs = {'href': re.compile((r'.*mail.*'))} ):
    print(node.get('href'))
```

If you do not need the "mailto:" - you can just replace it.

Comment: your code will show all email including invisible email.
I just need the visible one